# How do you force Windows to update DeskBand Min/Max range?

Tags: winapi, taskbar, windows-shell

I have a deskband and found that when choose to add it to the taskbar it asks for both the `DBIM_MINSIZE` and the `DBIM_ACTUAL`.  It always chooses to use the `DBIM_MINSIZE`.  After you first choose to use the deskband, if you choose to `lock`/`unlock` the taskbar, no WM_SIZE messages are sent. However if you resize even one pixel and put it back where it was, toggling the state sends the expected WM_SIZE message.  Now the deskband ignores changes to the width / height of `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` so it relies on the `DBIM_MINSIZE`.  The problem is if you slide it over to the minimum size then toggle the `lock`/`unlock` state of the taskbar, it makes the window a little wider which when having the taskbar with multiple rows can cause the icons / buttons to shift.  i.e. 3 on top, 3 on bottom when unlocked, then lock, 4 on top, 2 on bottom because the extra size allows one more to fit the width.  Therefore you have to make the `DBIM_MINSIZE` smaller than it really is, which again would be fine if the initial size was `DBIM_ACTUAL` otherwise, some of the icons/buttons are cut off on the initial enable of the deskband.

Question 1: Is there better way to manage the sizing of the deskband to handle the initial size to be actual minimum while allowing a smaller minimum size so lock/unlock gives desired result?

Also, if a button/icon is added or removed, the deskband doesn't request the `DIBM_MINSIZE` nor `DBIM_ACTUAL`.

Question 2: Is there a way to force the deskband to request the new DIBM_MINSIZE (lock / unlock will cause it, but how do you do it from the deskband itself)?

TIA!!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @df234987?